# Move Ajax respose data to store in Sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

how to add or save data that getting from ajax request to store or to model sencha touch 2
I have controller, store and a model. Ext.Ajax.request(); is called from controller and when it was successful I want move that data to store in json format

```
Ext.define('Myapp.controller.HomeController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        control: {

            "#homepage_id": {
                show: 'onHomepage_idShow'
            }
        }

    },


    onHomepage_idShow: function (component, eOpts) {

        var token = localStorage.getItem('Token'); //**************************************
        console.log('test home', token);

        var customHeaders = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'ApiAuth': token
        };

        this.callAjax(customHeaders);
    },
    callAjax: function (headers) {
        var customHeaders = headers;

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'http://localhost:9098/Folder/json/Get',
            params: Ext.util.JSON.encode({
                folderId: 0
            }),
            method: 'POST',

            headers: customHeaders,

            success: function (response) {
                var decode_text = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                /*I want to add decode_text to a store from this contoller..*/

                //var storez = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('commomStore_id');//****************

                //this.getDataList().setStore(storez);
                console.log(storez);


                // process server response here
            },
            failure: function (response, opts) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Error while submitting the form');
                console.log(response.responseText);
            },

            scope: this
        });
```

My Store:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.store.CommonStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'Myapp.model.AuthTokenmodel'],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'Myapp.model.AuthTokenmodel',
        storeId: 'commonStote_id',
        proxy: {

            type: 'localstorage',
            id: 'commomStore_id',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        fields: [{
            name: 'authtoken'
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to parse your response and create `Myapp.model.AuthTokenmodel` objects out of it and then add those objects to your store using `add` method.

BTW if your response is in JSOn format you should parse it to JSON instead of text like this:

```
var respObj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
console.log(respObj);
```

then create model objects using `respObj` data and add those to store:

```
var storez = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('commomStore_id');
storez.add(Ext.create('Myapp.model.AuthTokenmodel', {authtoken : respObj.authToken}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.getStore('commomStore_id').loadData(decode_text);
```